# Can't open FragmentActivity from Fragment/FragmentActivity in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent, android-fragments

I've got a problem I can't solve with my app's navigation drawer. One of the links in the navigation drawer is to open a FragmentActivity (which contains a ViewPager). The other links are Fragments. Right now I have it set up as an Intent to start that activity but I get an error about one of my Fragments, MapsPage. Something to do with nesting Fragments. I'll post the logcat below. This is now my NavigationDrawer onClick is set up:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Fragment newFragment = new MapsPage();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch(i) {
            case 0:
                newFragment = new FragOne();
                fm.popBackStack();
                break;
            case 1:
                newFragment = new FragTwo();
                fm.popBackStack();
                break;
            case 2:
                newFragment = new FragThree();
                fm.popBackStack();
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentPagerActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                fm.popBackStack();
                break;
            }
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, newFragment).addToBackStack("fragback").commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(rl);
}
```

My issue is with "case 3:". The MapsPage which is central to my app has a map fragment in the XML which is causing there to an exception when calling this. Here is the exception:

```
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950): Process: com.android.package.name, PID: 15950
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at com.mdev.bluestorm.drinki.MapsPage.onCreateView(MapsPage.java:103)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f060060, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

This is the key error:

**01-20 18:42:09.302: E/AndroidRuntime(15950): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f060060, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment**

Is there something I can do to prevent this? I need to be able to open the FragmentActivity from the navigation drawer without this force close because it's conflicting with the Google maps Fragment. I need the MapsPage to be part of the backstack, the only one in fact, as you can see I'm popping the backstack for every other page.

I would really appreciate some help on this, I'm lost on what to do next. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the XML file referenced.

Comment: Edited my question with the XML of the MapsPage Fragment added to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main,newFragment).addToBackStack("fragback").commit();
```

after you called `startActivity()`

Comment: Are you talking about the MapsPage or the FragmentActivity I am trying to open? The way I have the maps part is working well which is why I'm a little apprehensive to change it.

Comment: Ah I see. I tested it by commenting out fm.beginTransaction and the Intent worked. So I just have to call fm.beginTransaction for the other Fragments.